# types of jquery chosen and select2 multiselect

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2, jquery-chosen, jquery-ui-multiselect

i have two controls one `chosen multiselect` and another `select2 multivalue select`

**chosen multiselect**

```
<select id="mlti_1" class="chosen span6" multiple='multiple' >
  <option value="1">one</option>
  <option value="2">two</option>
  <option value="3">three</option>
</select>
```

**jquery multi value select**

```
<select id="mult_2" class="select2 span6" multiple='multiple'>
  <option value="1">ONE</option>
  <option value="2">TWO</option>
  <option value="3">THREE</option>
</select>
```

both controls are working fine, but the problem is when i am passing these Ids to JS function and trying to display it's type both are showing the type as `select-multiple`

**JS**

```
//no need to initiate chosen multiselect
$('#mult_2').multiSelect(); // initiating select2 multiselect
function displayType(id) // id = mult_val or drp_me
{
  var control=document.getElementById(id);
  console.log(control.type); // both controls showing as select-multiple
}
```

i am using jquery plugins for both controls. basically both are same select control (select). but physically they are different. `how i can differ these controls through code?? is there any solution for this?` [image: This is the screen shots of the controls]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By differ if you meant accessing them and their values using different handles, you can do that just by accessing their ids.

use `$("#mlti_1")` for accessing the `chosen` control and `$("#mult_2")` for the second multiselect control.

UPDATE :

As I said in the comment, you can use the following function to determine the type of the multi-select.

```
function displayType(id) // id = mult_val or drp_me
{
    var control = document.getElementById(id);
    console.log(control.type); // both controls showing as select-multiple
    if (control.classList.contains("chosen")) {
        console.log("chosen");
    } else if (control.classList.contains("select2")) {
        console.log("select2");
    }
}
```

provided, you assign proper class names(chosen and select2) to the various multi-selects in the HTML code.

Comment: no that will not help me.. i just want to know the type of control! or anything that distinguishing them..

Comment: `var control=document.getElementById(id);` using this `control` object how i can identify them separate???

Comment: i'm not sure you can do that or not. But you can assign separate class names to different selects and maybe find out the type by testing the class name inside the function.